# jQuery selected option disabled

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have made a function to disable an option that is already selected.
It works until I make another select option. If I change the second option, the first value becomes NULL. Then if I spawn in another one and select something, the first and second values become NULL.

Here I have the jsfiddle URL, with the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/fsao6t2z/

```
function changeKeuzes ()
{
    var keuzes = [];

    $('.keuzes').each( function ()
    {
        console.log($(this).find('option[disabled]'));
        if($(this).val() != 'Kies je optie'){
            keuzes.push($(this).val());
        }
    });


    $.each(keuzes, function(k, v)
    {
        $('.keuzes').each (function () {
            $(this).find('option[class="' + v + '"]').attr("disabled", true);
        });
    });


}
```

Comment: Your code is too heavy for us to troubleshoot it for you. If you can minimize your issue into a small, functional snippet, that will make things a lot easier.

Comment: @gerard: Can you make your code minimal so we can understand well

Comment: That is the problem because i am new to jQuery. I don't know how to do that. Could you maybe help me do that?